# Error while installing philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar package in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, package, fullcalendar

Hello I am installing philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar in my yii2 project.

But I am getting error :

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint >=~2: Invalid version string "~2"

I have read [this](https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar/issues/76) but nothing solved.

I want to use full calendar in my project so please suggest me any other package or guide me in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of fxp/composer-plugin has advised of a fix in progress. For now use this:

```
$ composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3@dev
```

And then:

```
$ composer update
```